# Refactoring rails calls to the database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rails-activerecord

How can I refactor this snippet so that it minimizes the number of calls to the database?

`/Player.rb`

```
def num_matchups
    this_week_appearances = 0
    this_week_appearances += Matchup.where(player_1: self.id).sum("pts_player_1")
    this_week_appearances += Matchup.where(player_1: self.id).sum("pts_player_2")
    this_week_appearances += Matchup.where(player_2: self.id).sum("pts_player_1")
    this_week_appearances += Matchup.where(player_2: self.id).sum("pts_player_2")
end
```

The goal is to find the number of times that the Player (whichever player this is called on) was in a Matchup that was voted on. Player could have been in in a Matchup in the `Matchup.player_1` or `Matchup.player_2` field (it makes no difference), and because I don't care about whether they won or lost (just number of appearances), I need the points from both players in the matchup.

I imagine it would look something like this, but I don't know the syntax that it should use:

```
this_week_appearances = Matchup.where(player_1: self.id OR player_2: self.id).sum("pts_player_1").sum("pts_player_2")
```

Can something like this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to find all the `Matchup`s where either `player_1` or `player_2` is `self.id` and then sum `pts_player_1` and `pts_player_2` for those `Matchup`s. The "either `player_1` or `player_2` part is easy to do at once:

```
Matchup.where('player_1 = :id or player_2 = :id', :id => self.id)
```

But how do you sum the points? Well, you can hand any SQL expression to `sum` so you can:

```
Matchup.where('player_1 = :id or player_2 = :id', :id => self.id)
       .sum('pts_player_1 + pts_player_2')
```

One problem you might have with this is that ActiveRecord won't be smart enough to know that `pts_player_1 + pts_player_2` is a number but a `to_i` call should sort that out:

```
Matchup.where('player_1 = :id or player_2 = :id', :id => self.id)
       .sum('pts_player_1 + pts_player_2')
       .to_i
```

The above assumes that you won't have any NULLs in `pts_player_1` or `pts_player_2`.